# Suggestions for my data structure/schema with Pouchdb - Couchdb

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Good morning!

I want to use couchdb/pouchdb for my pwa that I currently work on.

In my project I want to to store "Projects", in a "Project" I want to store the project-title and "Chapters", in a "Chapter" I want to store the chapter-title and "Scenes", a "Scene" contains contain text.

**What schema would make the most sense and performance?**

Right now I think about a plan like this:

- ## Project 1

  - *title: string*
  - ### Chapter 1

    - Scene 1

      - text: *string*
    - Scene 2

      - text: *string*
    - Scene 3

      - text: *string*
  - ### Chapter 2

    - ...
- ## Project 2

  - *title: string*
  - ### Chapter 1

    - Scene 1
    - ...

Since I only have SQL experience and never used document based databases before, I dont really know how to put a structure that makes sense.

**Do I store documents inside documents to have a schema that looks exactly like above or do I create a database for each component(Projects,Chapters,Scenes)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options.

1. Each project is a document with a list of chapters, each with a list of scenes.
2. Projects, chapters and scenes are three different kinds of documents in the same database.

Which one is the best depends on the likely total size, and how each of these components change. CouchDB works best with small documents (kilobytes). As you can only update whole documents, changing bits inside lists or inside objects in larger documents quickly become inefficient, and potentially generating update conflicts.

The second suggestion above will scale better, but (currently; see link below) lacks the convenience of being able to pull out everything about a project with a single API call. You can use the id field to great effect:

```
{
    "_id": "project1:toplevel",
    "type": "project",
    "title": "Project 1"
}

{
    "_id": "project1:chapter1",
    "type": "chapter",
    "title": "Project 1, chapter 1"
}

{
    "_id": "project1:chapter1#scene1",
    "type": "scene",
    "title": "Project 1, chapter 1, scene 1"
}
```

In a "landing soon" version of CouchDB this id format can be used to leverage so-called partitioned databases that would be a great fit here. You can read blog posts about it here:

https://blog.cloudant.com/2019/03/05/Partition-Databases-Introduction.html

Comment: Thank your for the answer! While reading your answer + article it clicked. But I have a concern, is there a native way to get like all chapters from a project?

Comment: I did! And I accidently replied while typing... Do you mind taking a look at my edited reply? :)

Comment: If you use the _id format above you should be able to use _all_docs with a suitable start and end key, something like startkey="project1:chapter"&endkey="project1:chapter/"

Comment: This is perfect! And the contra of having to use several API calls, doesnt really affect me, because I am using it locally and only remote sync all the data manually.

Thank you for your time spent on my question!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I dont really understand how to use the start and endkey for that case. Because I can't really exclude stuff. 
So when I am trying to get all chapters, I cant exclude the scenes from the results.

Comment: You can only use the range query on _all_docs trick to filter by one field. If you need to do more sophisticated grouping, you need to use a map - it's hard to type code in a comment -- I've implemented the scheme above with two views to give you chapters per project and scenes per project per chapter in https://skruger.cloudant.com/skey which is open for reading if you want to check it out. If you ask another Stack question I'd happily explain and show how to query it.

Comment: That helped me out a lot. While looking through the API docs i found something that works really well for me - Mango queries.
https://pouchdb.com/guides/mango-queries.html
That allows me to build secondary indexes.

Also I want to point out, that I found out about Cloudant because of you. I am gonna use that for this and future projects as my remote db. Thanks!